# IBM and Axis 1.4 web service's compatibility

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I'm facing a problem with web service.

I had a web service which long time was deployed and running on WebSphere application server using IBM web service's stack. Now I had migrated it to glassfish v2.1.1 to Axis 1.4 stack. Web service's WSDL did not change to keep clients compatibility

There is a web service method which has Boolean return type. The problem is when I call my method soap response returns different in glassfish:

Example:

WebSphere:

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <soapenv:Body soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <checkPendingOperationsResponse xmlns="http://operations.appserver.dealer.omnitel.lt">
            <checkPendingOperationsReturn xsi:type="xsd:boolean" xmlns="">0</checkPendingOperationsReturn>
         </checkPendingOperationsResponse>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Glassfish:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
      <soapenv:Body>  
         <ns1:checkPendingOperationsResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://operations.appserver.dealer.omnitel.lt">   
            <checkPendingOperationsReturn href="#id0"/>  
         </ns1:checkPendingOperationsResponse>  
         <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:boolean" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">false</multiRef> 
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The problem is that some clients is not able to handle "false", "true" values, because earlier returned values was "1", "0".

Is there a solution to this or substantiation that it is not possible to solve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Axis 1.x is a poor web-service stack, and in many cases is just broken. If you're going to migrate, then migrate to something more modern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to still return 1 and 0 for those values (corresponding to true and false) you can force the return class like it sais [here](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#InteroperatingWithUntypedServers) or create an interceptor that changes it before sending the response.

Comment: But I can not force or write any interceptors. If web service' returns Boolean it must return Boolean, not long, not int.
The problem is only with some clients which are generated using gSAOP.
"An XML Schema type mismatch"): Peculiar of the SOAP boolean type encoding is that it only defines the values 0 and 1, while the built-in XML Schema boolean type also defines the false and true symbolic constants as valid values.

Comment: Yes, you're right, what I'm proposing is more of a hack. Unfortunatelly I don't think there's anything else to do, unless you're willing to re-do the thing with a more modern SOAP Java framework (like CXF).